# Render django html text in email body format

Tags: django, django-templates

Below is a field on my forms.py:

```python
body = forms.CharField(label='Paste Email Thread Here',
                       widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
                                             "class": "body-QAerror",}))
```

And this is the data that I have entered:

[image]

Which I passed onto my html template; however, it didn't retain the email format (with indentions) See below:

> From: Firstname, Lastname Sent: Wednesday, February 27, 2019 11:01 AM To: someonelese@example.com Subject: server is unresponsive Importance: High For some unknown reason, the server is not responsive – can’t log in, and affected all end users. I filed a ticket 123456. Please communicate this if some users are asking for the issue. Thanks, Firstname MiddleName 78456431 FM@example.com

Is it possible to still retain the email format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML ignores whitespace. You'll need to convert those newlines to HTML tags.

There are built-in Django template filters to do this: [`linebreaks` and `linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks).

So you would do for example:

```
{{ email.body|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! 
I tried also doing the strip=False from the django documentation, it doesn't work even if i'm on django 2 already.